# Get the return value with ptrace using SINGLESTEP

Tags: c, linux, ptrace

I'm working on a little debugger under Linux 64bits and I'm having trouble looking for syscall's return value,

I'm testing RIP value, I mean I do a PEEK_USERDATA and ptrace give me the opcode in return no the RIP address, directly this way (where 0x050f is the opcode of SYSCALL):

```
if (rip & 0x0000ffff == 0x050f)
```

then get syscall name args etc

The problem is how do I get the return value of these syscalls, and I know ptrace provide PTRACE_SYSCALL to warn us about enterring/leaving kernel-mode but I'd like to check directly the RIP value so I'm using SINGLESTEP, I checked if my rip match the SYSLEAVE and SYSEXIT opcode but it never. The only way I can check the return value is actually by checking my orig_rax but I won't get the exit_group retval this way.

I know that the Linux ABI want the return value to be stored in RAX, but I don't how to witness a return to userland.

Thanks you.

Comment: rip is the instruction pointer -- it contains the address of the next instruction to execute, not the opcode bits of that instruction...

Comment: I do a PEEK to the location of RIP so ptrace give me back the opcode editing op

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't ptrace the kernel, so if you do another PTRACE_SINGLESTEP or PTRACE_SYSCALL after stopping at a SYSCALL, it will execute the system call and stop at the next instruction after it returns.  At that point, you can check the registers to see what the return value of the system call is.

Comment: Ok now I get it, I'm having an error with PTRACE_GETREGS, fixing that and approving this answer thanks you! EDIT: With a good place wait4(2) it works Thanks you very much!!